# Loading large images into image control

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I'm loading large images on a WPF window to make some adjustments (like brightness and contrast) but when I try to load a large image (3000x2000 or 4000x3000) my image converts automatically to a lower resolution (usually 1024x600)

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName));

imageResolution.Content = bitmap.Width + "x" + bitmap.Height;//label to see dimensions
myImage.Source = bitmap;//image
```

What can I do to keep the original resolution of my images in the BitmapImage object?

Comment: Could you post the XAML of your `myImage` control and it's containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an [ImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx) object instead:

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName));
image1.Source = imageSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange. Try to set myImage.Source directly in XAML.

Control should keep original image

```
<Image x:Name="image1" Stretch="None" Source={Binding PathToImage}>
```